# Read url from browser

Tags: php, url

I have the  following url: http://raiffeisenclub.www4.nextsoft.at/# bereich=6&_suid=132023551036703093549711221371 and I want to get this url via php. I tried it with

```
$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

but I just get  http://raiffeisenclub.www4.nextsoft.at then. Also

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

and

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

don't work. 
Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: Just to mention, it would be good if I'd just know that there is a #-symbol in my URL. So what could I do to find that out via php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser do not send the hash (the part after #) to the server, and because of this it is not available in PHP. You can read it and send it to the server only with JavaScript

> When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the
> identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from
> the URI by a crosshatch ("#") character, consists of additional
> reference information to be interpreted by the user agent after the
> retrieval action has been successfully completed. As such, it is not
> part of a URI, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.

[source](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-4)

Comment: So it is also not possible with $_GET('hash') ?

Comment: No, $_GET['hash'] would be somevalue in this case: ?hash=somevalue#hereisthehashpart. If you don't have ?hash it would be undefined

Answer (score 1):

Try with javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var pageurl = document.location.href;
</script>
```